Script Editor text not showing on clients, and Icons not tranparent on clients or with background image for site
First question
I have a Script Editor Web Part on the landing page of my SharePoint 2016 classic website, displaying text, Good morning (afternoon/evening), UserName,.  On the WFE server it is displayed correctly but on all clients not at all. I have changed the permission for a user to Edit and then it’s shown. But as it is on the landing page I cannot give Edit permission to every one. What am I doing wrong.
Second question
On the WFE server icons are displayed correctly, but for clients it seems to be not transparent, this is only the case when "Office" look is selected, for all others icons are solid squares the colour vary according to the look chosen.
Also the moment I change the look AND (even for Office) drop an image to change the background of the site ALL icons change to solid filled in squares, on WFE server and on all clients.
Your help are much appreciated.


Verify User Permissions: Confirm that users who are unable to see the text have at least Read permissions on the page where the Script Editor Web Part is placed. Without sufficient permissions, users won't be able to view the content of the Web Part.

Thank you very much for your answer. Permissions are not the problem as everybody has at least read permission.
